# PRG pattern or anything similar in ASP.NET WebPages

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages, post-redirect-get

**The question is centered around this concept:**
A website based on [asp.net-webpages](/questions/tagged/asp.net-webpages) includes a form that
when submitted executes a page, which includes the *WebMail Helper*.
That page then requests the values and sends them to my email address.

The only downside is that the page can be reloaded and it will resend the values.
To prevent this I will need to include a PRG pattern or anything similar to it.
Any help is much appreciated.

A solution would be useful for the next step, which is: adding an email confirmation step.

With the hope that I can avoid using the MVC pattern.

Comment: What do you want help with? Writing some code or understanding PRG?

Comment: You could just redirect back to your calling form: Response.Redirect(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]);

Comment: @MikeBrind Writing the code.

Comment: @AardVark71 What exactly does this accomplish?

Comment: Response.Redirect causes a client-side redirect because it sends the browser a 302 'object moved' http status. Along with it you can specify where it's moved to. For instance if you use Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"] you specify the form it was posted from. (If you want an email confirmation step you'll probably want to add a querystring parameter specifying the success )